# Python import as tuple

Tags: python, django

What's the difference between

```
from package import x, y
```

and

```
from package import (x, y)
```

I've seen this usage in Django source code but couldn't find the documentation for the second method (using round brackets around import)

- https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L5
- https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L13

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The statements are functionally equivalent.

From http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/, the use of parentheses was approved for enclosing long lists of imports in a pythonic way:

```
from Tkinter import (Tk, Frame, Button, Entry, Canvas, Text,
    LEFT, DISABLED, NORMAL, RIDGE, END)
```

It seems that parentheses were added for the second statement because the import list was too long.

Comment: Not especially long, but still 89 characters if put on one line. (The actual names are longer than `x` and `y`, of course.)

Comment: @user2357112 Whoops, didn't look at your links. You're completely right :) I edited the answer.